# Creating a query to display counts of specific results from a longtext field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello firstly I am a SQL newb and need a little help. I could not find a question exactly like mine.

```
(select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text1%')
(select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text2%')
(select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text3%')
```

So I want the search to return

```
case 1  | Case 2  | Case 3
xtimes   ytimes     ztimes
```

Any help would be great, either just display a queried result or creating a temporary table.

Cheers,

The solution I found was as follows

```
Select * from(
(select count(*)  as col1 from table  where Column_x like '%text1%')col1,
(select count(*)  as col2 from table  where Column_x like '%text2%')col2,
(select count(*)  as col3 from table  where Column_x like '%text3%')col3
```

)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
        (select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text1%') as xtimes,
        (select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text2%') as ytimes,
        (select count(*)  from table  where Column_x like '%text3%') as ztimes
        );
```

Comment: I am getting error 'Every derived table must have its own alias '